# Clustered indexes in Synapse Dedicated Pool and row storage

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I try to understand indexes in Azure Synapse and I'm a bit confused by some of them.

Regarding the **Clustered Columnstore Index**, I've a feeling that it works a bit like Apache Parquet, with row groups and column chunks inside. In **heap tables** the data is not indexed, so it seems pretty clear too.

But what about the **clustered** and **nonclustered indexes**? [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-index#clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes) defines them as:

> Clustered indexes may outperform clustered columnstore tables when a single row needs to be quickly retrieved. For queries where a single or very few row lookup is required to perform with extreme speed, consider a clustered index or nonclustered secondary index. The disadvantage to using a clustered index is that only queries that benefit are the ones that use a highly selective filter on the clustered index column. To improve filter on other columns, a nonclustered index can be added to other columns. However, each index that is added to a table adds both space and processing time to loads.

Here are my questions:

1. Does it mean they're more like the indexes from SQL Server? I mean, the clustered index would order the data by one column and store it as rows? And the non clustered would be an extra sorted index storing only references to the rows?
2. If my assumption about row-based format is correct, does it mean the clustered index is not performant for the analytical queries, doesn't it?
3. What happens if we create a table with both Columnstore and Clustered Indexes? The data is duplicated, once for the columnar format, once for the row format?

Some links I found on that topic, but still have some doubts whether they apply to Synapse:

- https://crmchap.co.uk/understanding-table-distribution-index-types-in-azure-synapse-analytics/
- https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/introduction-to-indexes-part-2-%e2%80%93-the-clustered-index
- [https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/introduction-to-indexes-part-3-%E2%80%93-the-nonclustered-index](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/introduction-to-indexes-part-3-%E2%80%93-the-nonclustered-index%C2%A0)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-azure-sql-data-warehouse?toc=%2Fazure%2Fsynapse-analytics%2Fsql-data-warehouse%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fsynapse-analytics%2Fsql-data-warehouse%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true#rowstore-table-heap-or-clustered-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bartosz,

> Does it mean they're more like the indexes from SQL Server? I mean, the clustered index would order the data by one column and store it as rows? And the non clustered would be an extra sorted index storing only references to the rows?

You are correct on clustering and non clustering definition - with a slight twist. It is similar to traditional SQL Server and that the leaf of cluster is the actual data row.
In summary, the physical organization of data rows for Synapse/pdw will be

- **Clustered columnstore** - data is not sorted and row segments can have overlapping min-max values
- **Clustered columstore** with order by - data is sorted, hence the row segments will not have overlapps and skipping will optimal
- **Heap**  - which is row format
- **Clustered index** this is SQL Server clustered index where lead/data portion is sorted.

> If my assumption about row-based format is correct, does it mean the clustered index is not performant for the analytical queries, doesn't it?

Clustered index will be performant if your query selects a set of values are sequential. for example - `select * from table where year between 2005 and 2007`. Row/Heap tables are efficient if your projection/select includes all or most of the columns of the table. Columnstore organization is efficient if have wide tables and select a handful of columns.

> What happens if we create a table with both Columnstore and Clustered Indexes? The data is duplicated, once for the columnar format, once for the row format?
> If you have a columstore index, you wont be able to create a clustered index.

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable   
  (  
    mycolumnnn1 nvarchar,  
    mycolumn2 nvarchar COLLATE Frisian_100_CS_AS )  
WITH ( CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX )  
;
```

Will fail with the error below:

> create clustered index idx1 on Mytable(mycolumnnn1)
> Msg 1902, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
> Cannot create more than one clustered index on
> table 'Mytable'. Drop the existing clustered index
> 'ClusteredIndex_d79fca6646664ddea0d5983cbb17a8ae'
> before creating another.

Comment: Thank you, Pradeep for such a detailed answer! It sheds some light on my doubts. Could you please reference any resources you have for the indexes organization? I only found the explanation applying to the SQL Server and would be happy to see something more Synapse-specific. I will accept the answer anyway :)

Comment: Bartosz, the following page helped me understand these structures better. especially when it talks about ordered by [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/performance-tuning-ordered-cci?view=azure-sqldw-latest ....there is a create table page on the left, go thru options in the of create table for synapse as well.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much! I missed this CREATE TABLE section and indeed, it helps :)